# A macro that won't run until another 3rd party process has completed

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm currently working on making some minor changes to a report.

It is an Excel file that uses a 3rd party addin to connect to a database and pull back information.

The part I have trouble in is that they would like the date and time that the report was run placed into the footer of the report.

I have pulled the date from the database through to a cell on the report, and I can pull this into the footer, however, all of the solutions i have tried so far need the user to perform an action to run the macro, e.g. click on another cell, activate the worksheet etc.

Is there a way I can set my macro to wait until another function/process has finished before it runs?

e.g. The users opens the workbook, then clicks Load All Sheets, which triggers the LoadAll function which populates the sheets etc, ideally I would like to run my macro automatically once this has finished.

Using call won't work, as if I make any changes to the 3rd party stuff those changes would need to be distributed to all users, and not every report needs the date in the footer

Comment: Share the code of LoadAll function. How do you call 3rd party addin?

Comment: I don't have access to the code of the loadall function. It is part of the UNIT4 Report Engine. All I can see is 

Public Sub agrxlLoadAll()
    agrxlImmediate "LoadAll"
End Sub

To run this the user would enter the variables such as company code and then go to the UNIT4 Excelerator tab then Load > All Sheets

I did consider a time delay on the macro, but while it runs relatively quickly on my sysetm using a test enviroment on a live system it could take considerably longer to run

Answer (score 0):

So, I think that I was approaching this in the wrong way.

I've spent sometime learning about Excel addins (it isn't something I have any experience of), and I don't believe that my macro would ever work in the way I want it to.

My limited understanding leads me to believe that the addin actually creates a new worksheet when the load all button is clicked, and this worksheet is populated with the data at the time it is created.

Therefore, the macro won't detect any changes, as there have been no changes made to the worksheet.